# Where is the Bios chip K53E

Tags: windows-10

[image]

I have a PC that can no longer boot into the BIOS

The power turns on, but it becomes unresponsive after the memory check lamp lights up.

I want to rewrite the BIOS RAM, but I don't know where the chip is.

[image]

Comment: *How* would you rewrite the BIOS RAM, assuming you knew where it was? Could you provide a reference as to how?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?  Are you trying to overwrite the BIOS Rom

Comment: There's ways to flash a rom with an in place programmer. I've done it but it needs quite a bit of skill - and frankly those images are too small unless you literally know what you're looking for

Comment: Its one of the 8 pin chips on the second image. Unfortunately the images provided are not really good enough to be certain. I do believe its the one between the ZIF connector and the round thing

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

second image
So it means it's behind

Do you mean the right or left side of the battery?
If I know which one, I will try reading and rewriting.

Comment: I plan to use the "CH314" program writer for rewriting.
I also have the BIOS image.

It is unconfirmed whether the BIOS is really broken, but since it is an immovable PC, I will try it.

Comment: Although there is a way to rewrite
I asked because the position of the chip is unclear.

Comment: I have rewritten the BIOS of other PCs in the past, so I know how to do it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Pbi.png I think its that. That said you WILL want to confirm using the markings on the chip.

Comment: also the process of using a in chip programmer is fiddly so double and triple confirm everything. And sometimes the clip itself is faulty and... its a bit frustrating.

Comment: Mr.  Journeyman Geek On Strike
Thank you for your answer.

I was able to confirm the description of the tip location.
I understand that it is difficult to write on the chip clip.

I'm planning to get a micro IC clip, so I'll try it.